# Select2.js and jQuery slideDown animation lag/jitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, select

I have a select2.js dropdown that I would like to animate; I would like the dropdown to slidedown instead of appear suddenly.

This is what I am doing now:

```
var select = $("#select").select2({
     minimumResultsForSearch: -1
});

$('#select').on('select2:open', function (e) {
    $("#select option[value='0']").remove();
    $('.select2-results').hide().slideDown("slow", "easeInOutQuint");
});
```

The problem is that the first time I open the drop down, there is a slight lag/jitter. Here is a more precise description of what is happening:

- Select container is clicked
- Select dropdown starts sliding down.
- 20% down the animation, it lags for like 0.2s (trying to eliminate that)
- Slide down then continues fine.

After the first time, the slideDown is flawless. It's just the first time that has the jitter/lag.

Any ideas?

Note that easeInOutQuint is coming from jQuery Mobile transitions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply it on .select2-dropdown with timeout function check below code how i did achieve that

```
jQuery('#select').on('select2:open', function (e) {
   jQuery('.select2-dropdown').hide();
   setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('.select2-dropdown').slideDown("slow", "easeInOutQuint"); }, 200);
});
```